# UnavailableShardsException when running tests with 1 shard and 1 node

Tags: elasticsearch

We are running our tests (PHP application) in Docker. Some tests use Elasticsearch.

We have configured Elasticsearch to have only 1 node and 1 shard (for simplicity). Here is the config we added to the default:

```
index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

Sometimes when the tests run, they fail because of the following Elasticsearch response:

```
{
  "_indices":{
    "acme":{
      "_shards":{
        "total":1,
        "successful":0,
        "failed":1,
        "failures":[
          {
            "index":"acme",
            "shard":0,
            "reason":"UnavailableShardsException[[acme][0] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned to a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: delete_by_query {[acme][product], query [{\"query\":{\"term\":{\"product_id\":\"3\"}}}]}]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error message extracted from the response:

> UnavailableShardsException[[acme][0] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned to a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: delete_by_query {[acme][product], query [{\"query\":{\"term\":{\"product_id\":\"3\"}}}]}]

Why would our client fail to connect to Elasticsearch's node or shard randomly? Is this something to do with the fact that we have only 1 shard? Is this a bad thing?

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with having one primary only. Your node is unresponssive/down for some reason. There you need to look at. Start with ES logs, they should say what's going on.